# how to link and apply external css file

Tags: c#, css

I have a css file named tablecellmembers.css (and is not yet linked in the .aspx file?) that contains:

```
td {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-top: thick;
    border-top-width: 5px;
    border-top-color: blue;
}
```

Then I created a table, table row, and table cell dynamically in the .cs file.

```
TableCell tc = new TableCell();
```

How can I apply that css file to my table cells?

I have tried:

```
tc.CssClass = "td";
tc.Attributes.Add("tablecellmembers", "td");
```

But the css is not being applied to the cells..

Comment: Where did `TableCell` come from?

Comment: In your css "td" isn't a css class name it's specifying the "td" html element. A classname would start with a "." e.g. ".myclassname".

Comment: just link your css file with your document and 'voilà' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `link` tag to the `<head>` of your ASPX page (or master page if you're using one) like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tablecellmembers.css">
```

You don't need to use CssClass or add any attributes as `td` is an element rather than a class. I recommend you read up on CSS selectors to clarify this.

In a nutshell, for the following element:

```
<td id="someID" class="someclass">...</td>
```

The following could be used in CSS to refer to it:

- `td { ... }` would apply to all `<td>` elements
- `#someID { ... }` applies to just the element with the id "someID"
- `.someclass { ... }` applies to all elements (td or otherwise) with the class "someclass"

Answer (score 2):

In the `head` section of your *aspx* or *master* page, add

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tablecellmembers.css">
```

You don't need to do anything to use your `td` style in your code behind, as this style will be applied to all table cells (HTML `td` elements).

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the reference of your css file in the `aspx page` within `head tag` (if you are not using master page) like this

```
<link href="your css file name" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Or if you are using a `content page` inherited from a `master page` then include above file reference at master page.

Answer (score 0):

Using `td` as a style name is bad practice, since it's easily confusable for the `td` element. To add the stylesheet in .NET, you can do this:

```
    var styleSheet = new HtmlLink();
    styleSheet.Attributes.Add("rel","stylesheet");
    styleSheet.Attributes.Add("href", "tablecellmembers.css");
    Page.Header.Controls.Add(styleSheet);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to first link the css file to the rendered aspx page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tablecellmembers.css">
```

Once this is done the style should be automatically applied to the table cells when they are rendered in the browser, you don't need to use attributes as the **td** selector has already linked the style to the table cell in the rendered html. Hope that helps.